# How to treat the variable as a value and not a string inside ''

Tags: for-loop, range, jinja2

I am using https://cryptic-cliffs-32040.herokuapp.com/

Template:

```
not in loop 1={{ports['1']}}
not in loop 2={{ports['2']}}

{% for n in range(1, 11) %}for loop {{n}}={{ports['n']}} {# here I wish to see ports['n'] as ports['1'] to ports['10']. But between '', n is treated as a string, which I am unable to undo/escape #}
{% endfor %}
```

Values:

```json
{
    "ports": {
        "1": "1G",
        "2": "2G",
        "3": "3G",
        "4": "4G",
        "5": "5G",
        "6": "6G",
        "7": "7G",
        "8": "8G",
        "9": "9G",
        "10": "10G"
    }
}
```

Render:

```
not•in•loop•1=1G
not•in•loop•2=2G

for•loop•1=
for•loop•2=
for•loop•3=
for•loop•4=
for•loop•5=
for•loop•6=
for•loop•7=
for•loop•8=
for•loop•9=
for•loop•10=
```

Comment: `for loop {{n}}={{ports[n|string]}}`

Comment: Thank a lot. This helped. Not sure where my original comment right after few mins of your comment went.